# Meshgrid an inconsistent dataset for a contour plot

Tags: python, mesh, contourf

I change my inconsistent dataset to a consistent dataset. Now i have this problem: I dont understand how to create a contour out of three 1D Dataframe columns.

How i can meshgrid them for the contour plot?
The three columns are:

```
data_month['Timestamp'], data_month['Altitude_[m]'], data_month['Horizontal_Wind_Speed_[m/s]']
```

The dimensions are:

```
Name:  Timestamp, Length: 10692, dtype: datetime64[ns]
--------
Name: Altitude_[m], Length: 10692, dtype: int64
---------
Name: Horizontal_Wind_Speed_[m/s], Length: 10692, dtype: float64
```

So how I could meshgrid, reshape them? The `data_month['Altitude_[m]']` repeats every 33 steps.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution.
For me this works.

```
yi = np.linspace(minimum_range_m, maximum_range_m, number_of_gates)
xi = list(set(pd.to_datetime(data_month['Timestamp'].values.tolist())))
xi.sort()

zi = data_month['Horizontal_Wind_Speed_[m/s]'].values.tolist()
Zi = np.reshape(zi, (len(xi),len(yi))).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cp = plt.contourf(xi, yi, Zi)
fig.colorbar(cp)
plt.show()
```